# Is there any way to fill the empty gap between two parts in an image?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

[Threshold image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqJ4e.png)

[Mouth part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RnJD.png)

[Extracted teeth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoCwk.png)

I am trying to make extraction for the teeth part only from the cropped mouth image but the threshold and mask way miss some teeth as shown in the extracted teeth image.

I am using python in do this by getting the threshold image then find contours based on the threshold image and extract the contour detected,
by this code:

```
labels = measure.label(threshold, connectivity=2, background=0)
mask = np.zeros(threshold.shape, dtype="uint8")
for label in np.unique(labels):
    if label == 0:
        continue
    labelMask = np.zeros(threshold.shape, dtype="uint8")
    labelMask[labels == label] = 255
    numPixels = cv2.countNonZero(labelMask)
    if numPixels > 600:
        mask = cv2.add(mask, labelMask)

cv2.imshow("mask", mask)


_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(equa, contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow("thre",equa)
img_contours= cv2.findContours(mask,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
img_contours = sorted(img_contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

for i in img_contours:

    if cv2.contourArea(i) > 1000:

        break

mask = np.zeros(mask.shape[:2], np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [i],-1, 255, -1)
new_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
cv2.imshow("Image with background removed", new_img)
```

So is there anyway to make extraction and get all teeth or fill the empty gap between the extracted teeth?

Comment: I don't understand how you are doing the thresholding, but probably that's an area that can be improved. Check out the official [OpenCV Python tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html). It's not clear why you need contours for this problem. You should be able to use the thresholded image as a mask for the original to get just the teeth.

Comment: Please show original image before thresholding and your thresholding code. Perhaps we can suggest an improvement on the threshold result.

Comment: The original image is the mouth part above. And the threshold code
 ``` 
ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(equa, 138,255, 0)
threshold = cv2.erode(threshold, None, iterations=2)
threshold = cv2.dilate(threshold, None, iterations=4)  
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to use a different approach:
convert to HSV colorspace and use just the Hue channel, then do some thresholding and morphing to get the mask.

```
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h, s, v = cv2.split(img_hsv)
```

Maybe you want to blur the `h` channel before thresholding.

```
h_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(h, (5, 5), 1)
```

For the thresholding on the h channel I suggest you to use the GUI for some interactive adjustment

```
ret, thh_blur = cv2.threshold(h_blur, 9, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

You can use `thh_blur` as a mask and see if it is good for you or follow with some e morphing:

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5))
morphed_th = cv2.morphologyEx(thh_blur, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations = 1)
morphed_th = cv2.morphologyEx(morphed_th, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations = 2)
```

Finally use `morphed_th` as a mask:

```
res = img.copy()
res[morphed_th == 0] = 0
res
```

I got the following image.

[image]

I don't know if it good for you since it misses the side teeth in the darker corners, but you can extract them from the `s` channel and add to the mask.

If you want to get rid of the gap between theet (darker region) you can follow more or less the same logic starting from `res` as input image and playing with channels, thresholding etc.

---

**Adding the left side requires to play with parameters.**

This is the code. Do the same for the opposite side.

```
# blur the s channel
s_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(s, (5, 5), 1)

# custom thresholding
val1 = 240
val2 = 170
ths_blur = s_blur.copy()
ths_blur[ths_blur > val1] = 0
ths_blur[ths_blur > val2] = 255
ths_blur[ths_blur <= val2] = 0

# add to the previous and slice the left part
mask = cv2.add(morphed_th, ths_blur)
left = np.s_[:,0:70]

# apply morphology to the left slice
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
morphed_mask_left = cv2.morphologyEx(mask[left], cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations = 6)

# override the mask with the morphed left part
final_mask = morphed_th.copy()
final_mask[left] = morphed_mask_left

# use the mask
res_final = img.copy()
res_final[final_mask == 0] = (0, 0, 0)
res_final
```

This is what I get.

[image]

**To get a better understanding of why I did this way, plot each step. Maybe this allow you to find an even better solution.**

Comment: Okay. This is good but how I add the extracted from s channel too. Can you help me in it, please?  @iGian

Comment: Thank you very much. @iGian

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the answer to your very question is essentially negative.

The binary image has low information content, and there is no difference between a missing tooth and normal spacing around and between teeth.

With no a priori information on what a tooth pattern looks like, no low-level vision operation (filters) can help. You might be able to get some improvement by mapping a geometric model with a teeth layout, but this would not reflect the particular anatomy at hand and would be quite difficult to implement.

You must certainly work this out *before* binarization.